# Oracle PHP display only once

Tags: php, oracle

There are two tables:

[image: second table]

[image: first table]

```
$inner_query = 
    "SELECT A.*, ROWNUM AS RN, TO_CHAR(A.last_newsletter_modify, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS LAST_NEWSLETTER_MODIFY2
     FROM ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_subscription A,
          ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_type B,
          ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_subtyp_profile C
     WHERE A.id_subscription = C.id_subscription AND
           C.id_type = B.id_type
     ORDER BY e_mail";
```

If I run this query for id_subscription 734 it displays 3 times.

How can to display it just once?

Comment: Are you sure you're not outputting it several times within the HTML markup?

Comment: `C.id_type = B.id_type` should only result in one, how it comes that you have 3 entries for the 734 in the first table? Can  id_subscription  have more than one type_id? Very unclear. What is currently type_id for 734  in the second table? Are there more than on entries for 734 in the second table? What is the current result that you get from sql?

Comment: Take a look around `GROUP BY id_subscription` function

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions yes id_subscription can have up to 5 id_type

Comment: Are there more than one entries for 734 in the second table (actual)?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions for id_subscription 734 there are 3 entries in the second table.

Comment: So your sql working correct. Test `C.id_type = B.id_type AND C.id_type = 1` and you will get one result.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions yes but that displays me only id_subscription witch has the id_type = 1 . If i have a id_subscription 755 with id_type = 2 id_type = 3 it will not be displayed

Comment: `If i run this query for id_subscription 734 it displays 3 times. How can i do to display it just once.` sry, im out , get clear about what you want.

Comment: The question would be clearer without the PHP. Also, you have three tables not two, and it's not clear which one has an `e_mail` column.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you are getting one row per `newsletter_subtyp_profile`. Subscription 734 is linked to three newsletter types, hence three rows of output.

You have three tables, not two, and the question would be clearer if you included full descriptions and sample data, and also got rid of the irrelevant PHP aspect and focussed on the SQL.

With some detective work, I make it this:

```sql
create table newsletter_subscription
( id_subscription         integer primary key
, last_newsletter_modify  date
, e_mail                  varchar2(50) not null );

create table newsletter_type
( id_type                 integer primary key
, description             varchar2(40) not null unique );

create table newsletter_subtyp_profile
( id_subscription         references newsletter_subscription
, id_type                 references newsletter_type
, constraint nsp_pk       primary key (id_type,id_subscription) );

insert into newsletter_subscription values (600, date '2017-01-10', 'someone@somewhere.net');
insert into newsletter_subscription values (734, date '2017-02-05', 'someone@somewhereelse.net');
insert into newsletter_subscription values (800, date '2017-03-01', 'nobody@nowherewhere.net');

insert into newsletter_type values (1, 'Type One');
insert into newsletter_type values (2, 'Type Two');
insert into newsletter_type values (3, 'Type Three');

insert into newsletter_subtyp_profile values (734, 1);
insert into newsletter_subtyp_profile values (734, 2);
insert into newsletter_subtyp_profile values (734, 3);
```

Now run your query (I shortened the `select` list to simplify the output, and added `b.description` - a dummy column as I don't know what other columns you have on `newsletter_type`):

```
select a.id_subscription, a.e_mail
     , to_char(a.last_newsletter_modify, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as last_newsletter_modify2
     , b.description
from   newsletter_subscription a,
       newsletter_type b,
       newsletter_subtyp_profile c
where  a.id_subscription = c.id_subscription and
       c.id_type = b.id_type
order by a.e_mail, c.id_type;

ID_SUBSCRIPTION E_MAIL                     LAST_NEWSLETTER_MODIFY2 DESCRIPTION
--------------- -------------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------
            734 someone@somewhereelse.net  05/02/2017              Type One
            734 someone@somewhereelse.net  05/02/2017              Type Two
            734 someone@somewhereelse.net  05/02/2017              Type Three
```

btw the logic would be clearer if you used mnemonic aliases such as `sub` instead of `a` for `newsletter_subscription`, and also used standard ANSI joins and lost the uppercase:

```
select sub.id_subscription, sub.e_mail
     , to_char(sub.last_newsletter_modify, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as last_newsletter_modify
     , typ.description
from   newsletter_subscription sub
       join newsletter_subtyp_profile pro on pro.id_subscription = sub.id_subscription
       join newsletter_type typ on typ.id_type = pro.id_type
where  sub.id_subscription = 734
order  by sub.e_mail, pro.id_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `row_number` to get one row per id_subscription with max (or min id_type if you change the order by clause in the function to `order by id_type`):

```
  $inner_query = "SELECT *
                    FROM (
                        SELECT A.*, 
                            ROWNUM AS RN,
                            TO_CHAR(A.last_newsletter_modify, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS LAST_NEWSLETTER_MODIFY2,
                            row_number() over (
                                partition by C.id_subscription
                                order by C.id_type desc nulls last
                                ) as seqnum
                        FROM ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_subscription A
                        JOIN ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_subtyp_profile C 
                            on A.id_subscription = C.id_subscription
                        JOIN ".$db_schema_name."newsletter_type B
                            on C.id_type = B.id_type 
                        ) t 
                    WHERE seqnum = 1
                    ORDER BY e_mail";
```

Also notice that I have replace the old comma based join with widely recommended explicit JOIN syntax.